# Why am I getting this runtime error?

Tags: excel, vba

very new at coding and first post on here. I have searched all over the place but could not figure out what is wrong with my code. Basically I am trying to calculated some averages from data on another workbook. The error that I get when I run the following code "Runtime error 1004, Application-defined error or method-defined error" seems to be generated from the line where I reference to the other workbook in order to carry out the Match method. It looks like it should work for me but the error says otherwise... Thanks for your help

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("X:\Data Analysis\Process & Wall Loss Data Analysis\***** CT 12 HR AVG rev2.xlsm")
Dim nrow As Integer, conv_start As Double, conv_end As Double, avg1 As Double, avg2 As Double
nrow = Cells(9, 12)
For i = 1 To nrow
    conv_start = Application.VLookup(Cells(14 + i, 12), Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(300, 3)), 2, True)
    conv_end = Application.VLookup(Cells(14 + i, 13), Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(300, 3)), 2, True)
    avg1 = Application.Match(conv_start, wbk.Worksheets("PC & Wear").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(626, 1)), 1)
    avg2 = Application.Match(conv_end, wbk.Worksheets("PC & Wear").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(626, 1)), 1)
    For j = 1 To 40
        Cells(42 + j, 11 + i) = Application.Average(Range(Cells(avg1, 1 + j), Cells(avg2, 1 + j)))
    Next j
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: You need to qualify all range objects; `range` and `cells` to a worksheet.  For example `nrow = Cells(9, 12)` should be something like this: `nrow = wbk.sheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 12)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wbk.Worksheets("PC & Wear").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(626, 1))
```

Here `Cells()` will refer to the activesheet, not to the sheet in the other workbook, so the code will fail whenever "PC & Wear" is not the active sheet.

You should fully-qualify all uses of `Range()` and `Cells()` with a worksheet object:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = wbk.Worksheets("PC & Wear")
'...
avg1 = Application.Match(conv_start, sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(626, 1)), 1)
'...
```

Note it's best to do this even for cases where you expect to use the ActiveSheet - later on you may develop your code further and end up with some other sheet being active, and your code will break (or worse, it will still work but produce wrong output).

A further improvement would be to define a range variable to avoid repeating yourself:

```
Dim rngLU As Range
Set rngLU  = wbk.Worksheets("PC & Wear").Range("A1:A626")
'...
avg1 = Application.Match(conv_start, rngLU, 1)
'...
```

Comment: The only exception to the 'You should fully-qualify all uses of Range() and Cells() with a worksheet object' is when developing generic tools that may be used with any worksheet.

Comment: @dnep that is assuming that this 'tool' is always going to run on the active worksheet - if you want something to _truly_ work with any worksheet then you should absolutely qualify ranges with the worksheet object. In terms of "best practice" there isn't really an exception because qualifying ranges on the active sheet will still work.

Comment: Even when expecting to use the ActiveSheet, I like to declare a worksheet object and explicitly set that to the ActiveSheet: it avoids any question as to which sheet the code is intended to work on (be nice to people who may need to maintain your code!)

Comment: Hey thanks by fully qualifying my cells I was able to get rid of that error! However that same line now gives me the error '9' "Subscript out of range". I am sure the range that I am reference exist in the other workbook, then what do you think causes it? Thanks

Comment: @TimWilliams and MacroMan good point - it is definetly best practice to be explicit about ActiveSheet.

Comment: I suggest you break execution and then test each cell reference and the range in the immediate window, to check wich one is trigering the error (e.g. `Print sht.Cells(3, 2).Address`)

Comment: Seems likely you don't have a sheet with that name in the workbook you opened.

Comment: I fixed it!! I forgot to use "set" when I declared the worksheet, it's all working now :D Thanks a lot